Clipped parts of the image extend beyond the boundaries of the container in flutter
I have one image container. when clip image that time some image part is show outside of the container.
i add one image the right side of image part outside of container.
 child: Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: _isSelected && _showAlternateContainer ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
            child: ClipRect(
               clipper: MyCustomClipper( clipLeft, clipTop, clipWidth, clipHeight),
                child: Image.asset(
                        image,
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
              ),
            ),



Don't know about your custom clipper, but I guess the container is ended here as marked in the image.
You can give a padding to fit it or decrease the size of the image.
